# Firebase cloud functions not catching with fast database updates

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Hello I am trying to build a multiplayer game.
I have got a working queue:

```
.ref('Multiplayer/Queue/{queueCategory}/Players/{playerid}')
     .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {

         const root = snapshot.ref.root;

         var category = context.params.queueCategory;
         const gameDir = "Multiplayer/Active/" + category;
         var gameID = snapshot.ref.root.child(gameDir).push().key;

         root.child("Multiplayer/Queue/" + category + "/Players").once("value").then(players => {
             var secondplayer: DataSnapshot | null = null;
             functions.logger.log(players.numChildren());
             players.forEach(player => {
                 if(player.val() === "placeholder" && player.key !== context.params.playerid) {
                     secondplayer = player;
                 }
             });
             functions.logger.log(secondplayer);
             if(secondplayer === null) return null;

             root.child("Multiplayer/Queue/" + category + "/Players").transaction(function (matchmaking) {

                 //check if player joined differnet game
                 if (matchmaking === null || matchmaking === undefined || secondplayer === null || matchmaking[context.params.playerid] !== "placeholder" || matchmaking[secondplayer?.key || 1] !== "placeholder") return matchmaking;

                 matchmaking[context.params.playerid] = gameDir + "/" + gameID + "/player1";
                 matchmaking[secondplayer.key || -1] = gameDir + "/" +gameID + "/player2";

                 return matchmaking;

             }).then(result => {

                 var playerval: string  = result.snapshot.child(context.params.playerid).val();
                 var pPath = playerval.split('/');
                 pPath.pop();
                 playerval = pPath.join('/');
                 functions.logger.log("playervalue: " + playerval);
                 functions.logger.log("gamedir: " + gameDir + gameID);
                 if(playerval !== gameDir + "/" + gameID) return;

                 var game = {
                     gamestate: "init",
                     category: category,
                     Players: {
                         "player1": "",
                         "player2": ""
                     }
                 }
                 root.child(gameDir + "/" + gameID).set(game).then(snap => {
                     return null;
                 }).catch(error => {
                     console.log(error);
                 })
             }).catch(error => {
                 console.log(error);
             })
             return  null;
         }).catch(error => {
             console.log(error);
         })

     });
```

This script pairs up players and changes the value of the player in queue to the new gameroom
dir
. Everything works, except when to many players join the queue at once (
breaks down at roughly 1player/sec). I suspect the problem is in this part of the code:

```
             var secondplayer: DataSnapshot | null = null;
             functions.logger.log(players.numChildren());
             players.forEach(player => {
                 if(player.val() === "placeholder" && player.key !== context.params.playerid) {
                     secondplayer = player;
                 }
             });
             functions.logger.log(secondplayer);
             if(secondplayer === null) return null;
```

If to many players join the second player will be overlapping with other instances of the functions and ultimately the will terminate after the second player value has been set.
How can I fix this?
Please help me

Answer (score 0):

Cloud functions do not guarantee order of execution. There is a [Firecast](https://youtu.be/MzTS6mFDGjU) explaining parallel execution. You can take a look at [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) but your use case doesn't seem to be straightforward as incrementing or decrementing a value.

> Cloud functions (any serverless functions) may not be the best choice for all the cases.

You will have to make sure the user is deleted from the node immediately once is player is matched. Using transactions you can match and remove 2 players immediately. So when a third user who was about to match as well will be added to queue instead of in the queue.

You may need queues running on your server (if the reads and writes are so high speed) or refactor the logic that matches your players. [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) may be a better choice for this. You may be able to use something like [OpenMatch](https://openmatch.dev/site/) with that.

I remember stacking up all the users trying to match in an array and then running a cron job every 2 seconds to make pairs of them. Then I had used realtime database to emit changes to relevant users. Although this may not not be possible in cloud functions as each functions runs independently of each other.